# Why SQL-query in Postgres gives one time, but same raw query in Django gives out the same time, but without the time zone?

Tags: django, postgresql

In Postgres do next:

```
    SELECT data,message,timestamp FROM "table" 
    WHERE id_source='asdf'AND 
    "timestamp" BETWEEN '2016-09-27 00:00:00.000'::timestamp AND '2016-09-27 23:59:59.000'::timestamp 
    LIMIT 300
```

and get date and time row as **2016-09-27 15:03:00.759+03**

At Django:

```
with connections['db'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT data,message,timestamp FROM "table" 
        WHERE id_source='asdf'AND 
        "timestamp" BETWEEN '2016-09-27 00:00:00.000'::timestamp AND '2016-09-27 23:59:59.000'::timestamp 
        LIMIT 300""")
    querySet = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm get date and time **2016-09-27 12:03:00.759+00**
What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. `SET timezone=0` in psql console to get the same result, timezone is connection dependent

Comment: As @cske said. At connection time, Django issues a SET TIMEZONE, which sets the database connection timezone to the value specified in your settings file. This makes the client see timestamps as defined per the requested time zone.

Also, timezones are present in both of your examples. First it's +3hrs, the second is +0 hours.

Comment: @hruske ok, how get 2016-09-27 15:03:00.759+03 using Django query?

Comment: @vita_l.93 configure django to use timezone +3, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: @cske thanks! It works.

Answer (score 0):

At *settings.py* change next values:

```
TIME_ZONE = None
USE_TZ = False
```